# Loading Images in Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms, image

Currently I am loading Images stored on a network shared drive as Image byte array and loading using the Image byte array.
This takes quite some time to load.

Is there any other better way to load images which are stored on another machine in the network?

Comment: How long is "quite some time"? Also, are you just reading one byte at a time?

Comment: Define "loading"; copying? rendering? displaying? image manipulation? calculating checksum?

Comment: Is it possible to store it locally and load it from local location?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If working with images over the network, loading as Image byte array, it just takes time. That work has to be shared with other work over the network. With some code examples of how you are loading, I might be able to provide a better answer.